# FedEx API returns

Tags: fedex

What is the difference between RATED_ACCOUNT_PACKAGE and PAYOR_ACCOUNT_PACKAGE? What about RATED_LIST_PACKAGE and PAYOR_LIST_PACKAGE? I checked the [documentation](http://www.fedex.com/templates/components/apps/wpor/secure/downloads/pdf/Aug13/RateServices_WSDL_Guide.pdf) but it's somewhat confusing:

```
Use the optional RateRequestTypes element to have list rates returned
with discount rates. If you choose LIST as the element value, you receive
both discount and list rates, in addition to automation rate quotes.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it was explained to me, 'RATED' is the returned rate based on the origin country within your XML request and 'PAYOR' is the returned rate based on the country that's been setup at your account level.  I'd image that most of the time these two rates would be the same unless your XML origin country differs from the country setup on your FedEx account.

Note that FedEx removed the 'RATED' rates from their latest rate (v16) and ship (v15) WSDL.  Due to that I'd recommend not using 'RATED' but instead use the 'PAYOR' rates.